# Is $x\sin(\frac{1}{x}),\;0<x<\infty$ uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, continuity

I want to prove or disprove that $x\sin(\frac{1}{x}),\;0<x<\infty$ is uniformly continuous. Can anyone please, help me?

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: @José Carlos Santos: This question is different from the one thought to be its duplicate. This question is on $0<x<\infty$ not $\Bbb{R}.$

Comment: @Mike If you can do it in $\mathbb R$, you can do it in $(0,+\infty)$ and vice-versa.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos: Yes, I've done it! Thank you!